# Apply a function per matrix cell for multiple matrices numpy

Tags: python, matrix, time-series, numpy-ndarray

I'll try to simplify my actual problem.
Let's say I have 3 matrices with similar shape:

```
m1
array([[0.1 , 0.12, 0.32],
       [0.22, 0.15, 0.16],
       [0.42, 0.52, 0.62],
       [0.44, 0.35, 0.36]])

m2
array([[0.12 , 0.144, 0.384],
       [0.264, 0.18 , 0.192],
       [0.504, 0.624, 0.744],
       [0.528, 0.42 , 0.432]])

m3
array([[0.106 , 0.1272, 0.3392],
       [0.2332, 0.159 , 0.1696],
       [0.4452, 0.5512, 0.6572],
       [0.4664, 0.371 , 0.3816]])
```

Each matrix has a corresponded date, which I convert to an integer and call it delta, so:

```
delta_m1  = 2
delta_m2 = 5
delta_m3 = 10
```

What I would like to do is to apply a function to each cell-based-time-series, meaning that if I consider all cells at position `(0,0)`, then m1_cell is 0.1, m2_cell is 0.12, and m3_cell is 0.106. So now I have a cell-based-time-series where the time (the x-axis) being the deltas `(2,5,10)` and the y-axis is the value of the cells `(0.1,0.12,0.106)`. I would like to apply a smooth function (that takes two 1d-arrays and outputs 1d-array) that takes this cell-based-time-series, meaning takes `X=(2,5,10)` and `y=(0.1,0.12,0.106)` and outputs a new value per date/delta/matrix, so, for example, an output could be `(0.09,0.1,0.8)`, where each value corresponds to the cell at `(0,0)` for each matrix. The whole process I've described refers to only one cell. I would like to apply it to all cells. Then I can create new matrices based on the results. I guess I can simply iterate over each cell over each matrix, and apply the function, but that seems super not efficient.
How can I achieve that in a pythonic efficient way?

**EDIT**

The function I would like to apply on each cell-based-time-series:

```
def local_regression(x0, X, Y, k):
    # add bias term
    x0 = np.r_[1, x0]
    X = np.c_[np.ones(len(X)), X]
    
    # fit model: normal equations with kernel
    xw = X.T * radial_kernel(x0, X, k)
    beta = np.linalg.pinv(xw @ X) @ xw @ Y
    
    # predict value
    return x0 @ beta

def radial_kernel(x0, X, k):
    return np.exp(np.sum((X - x0) ** 2, axis=1) / (-2 * k * k))

def smooth(x,y):
    return [local_regression(x[p],x,y,k) for p in range(len(x))]
```

So for example:

```
y = np.array([2,5,10])
x = np.array([0.1,0.12,0.106])
smooth(x,y)
>>> array([5.14556944, 6.34810085, 5.50632924])
```

Where `x` is an array of integers (though it can be changed to float) and `y` is an array of float. `k` is a parameter of the function and here `k=20`

Comment: Could you elaborate what is the function you are looking at? maybe a dummy function and expected output? The reason is that the solution will differ based on the operations you want to perform.

Comment: @AkshaySehgal - I edited a bit the question - the function is a smoothing function that takes two 1d-arrays (delta, values) and outputs new values (1d-array)

Comment: Hi did you try my answer below with your function?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal - I added the function I would like to apply. Your solution worked for a single cell, meaning that this `f(D, M[:,0,0])`  gave me a result, but this `f(D[:,None,None], M)` ended with an error - `ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 2 dimension(s)`

Comment: Please vectorize the function. I have added the part with that -> `vf = np.vectorized(f)`
and then `vf(D[:,None,None], M)`

Comment: That didn't work as well, I get `TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()`

Comment: Can you add the part where you mention that `f(D, M[:,0,0]`) is running?

Comment: Does smooth take in x and y of shapes (3,) and (3,)? or x and y are integers?

Comment: I am unable to run `smooth(D, M[:,0,0])` to begin with, which you show in code. Can you see what is the issue in your functions? The vectorize function should work then.

Comment: I identified the issue to your paramter `k` what is k here? You have not provided that info anywhere.

Comment: The `x` and `y` in the smooth function can be integers or floats, it does not matter for the function, in my case `x` is an integer (though I can change the type) and `y` is float. `x` and `y` are indeed of shapes `(3,0)`. When `D = np.stack([2, 5, 10])` and I apply `smooth(D,M[:,0,0])` I get `array([0.10713757, 0.10847502, 0.11017182])`, and `k=20`, I forgot

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: Great, it works! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with broadcasting is primarily because you are using a list comprehension in the last function. What happens because of that is that your function only operates on the last dimension (axis=-1). This means you are forced to transpose your inputs even with `np.vectorize` and then transpose them back.

Plus, because of this you will have to explicitly mention the signature in the `np.vectorize` as well.

Check the code below. I have marked the areas where I have made changes.

```
#Stack all the matrices (because similar shape)
M = np.stack([m1, m2, m3])                   #(3, 4, 3)
D = np.stack([delta_m1, delta_m2, delta_m3]) #(3,)

##################### FUNCTION ######################
k=20

def local_regression(x0, X, Y, k):
    # add bias term
    x0 = np.r_[1, x0]
    X = np.c_[np.ones(len(X)), X]
    
    # fit model: normal equations with kernel
    xw = X.T * radial_kernel(x0, X, k)
    beta = np.linalg.pinv(xw @ X) @ xw @ Y
    
    # predict value
    return x0 @ beta

def radial_kernel(x0, X, k):
    return np.exp(np.sum((X - x0) ** 2, axis=1) / (-2 * k * k))

def smooth(x,y):
    return np.array([local_regression(x[p],x,y,k) for p in range(len(x))]) #<-----

smooth_v = np.vectorize(smooth, signature='(i),(i)->(i)') #<----
##################################################

smooth_v(D[None, None,:], M.transpose(2,1,0)).transpose(2,1,0)  #<----- 
#First transpose brings axis=0 to axis=-1, and the second transpose reverses it.
```

```
array([[[0.10713757, 0.12856508, 0.34284022],
        [0.23570265, 0.16070635, 0.17142011],
        [0.44997779, 0.55711536, 0.66425293],
        [0.4714053 , 0.37498149, 0.38569525]],

       [[0.10847502, 0.13017003, 0.34712007],
        [0.23864505, 0.16271253, 0.17356004],
        [0.4555951 , 0.56407012, 0.67254514],
        [0.4772901 , 0.37966258, 0.39051008]],

       [[0.11017182, 0.13220618, 0.35254982],
        [0.242378  , 0.16525773, 0.17627491],
        [0.46272164, 0.57289345, 0.68306527],
        [0.484756  , 0.38560136, 0.39661854]]])
```